# DB2 Load from delimitited Files - escape " in Fields doesn't work

Tags: db2, csv

I bet it's totaly simple and i just don't see it, but i don't get it ..

I execute the following command in DB2 command line processor:

> DB2 LOAD FROM "DB_ACC_PASS_REGEXP.del" OF DEL METHOD P (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) MESSAGES "DB_ACC_PASS_REGEXP.del.msg" INSERT INTO DB_ACC_PASS_REGEXP (APP_ID,APREGEXP,EXPLAIN_TEXT,ID,OPT_KZ) NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE REBUILD

Which loads the Data specified in following File into the database.

> 1,"[a-z]",,1,0
>
> 1,"[A-Z]",,2,0
>
> 1,"[0-9]",,3,0
>
> 1,"[!|\"|§|$|%|&|/|(|)|=|?|`|´|*|+|~|'|#|-|_|.|:|,|;|µ|<|>| |°|^]",,4,0
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> Here is the Problem

The Problem is, that only 3 of these 4 inserts will be accepted. The last one will be rejected, because DB2 Load doesn't notice the escape character before the double quotation mark.

if I change the last line to:

> 1,"[!|x|§|$|%|&|/|(|)|=|?|`|´|*|+|~|'|#|-|_|.|:|,|;|µ|<|>| |°|^]",,4,0
>
> ```
>    ^
> ```
>
> Here is the changed character

there is no problem ..

WHY doesn't the escape character "\" work??

**edit**
Okay.. I just tryed it the oracle way now and that works ... I escape " with another " so my Line looks like

> 1,"[!|""|§|$|%|&|/|(|)|=|?|`|´|*|+|~|'|#|-|_|.|:|,|;|µ|<|>| |°|^]",,4,0

But that's only a way to do it .. That doesn't explain why IBM offers the Backslash as an escape character (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0008305.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using LOAD with ascii / delimited files requires to tune the file type modifiers (look on Table 6 and Table 8 of the docu page you linked). I am not quite sure, but I can't remember using backslash as escape character in DB2.

You can either use another character delimiter as double quotes with **chardel** option or force no character delimiter with **nochardel** option.

BUT ...

In your case you need special characters as regular expressions, so you will always need to escape " with "" and ' with ''. I think there is no other way to get this working.