# DB2 Export - how is chardel escaped if it is contained in text?

Tags: csv, db2, db2-luw

Actually, the title should be self explaining. I give an example:

How will this text column be exported by DB2 Export (with default chardel and coldel)?

```
The name is "John".
```

The question
[DB2 Load from delimitited Files - escape " in Fields doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984132/db2-load-from-delimitited-files-escape-in-fields-doesnt-work) mentions double quote as the escape character.

The documentation says nothing about escaping:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html

I also have no access to DB2 to test it myself ...

**How are chardel (or coldel) escaped by DB2 export when they occur in text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doubled delimiter:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0011047.html

I should fully RTFM first..